# Repeated Entry Error Message - Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

As soon as I include `\bibliography{Literature}` in my code, I get the following error message:

> Transcript written on THESISSS.log.
>   This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: THESISSS.aux
>   The style file: ecca.bst
>   I couldn't open database file LIT.bib
>   ---line 112 of file THESISSS.aux
>    : \bibdata{LIT
>    :             }
>   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
>   I found no database files---while reading file THESISSS.aux

Frankly speaking, I have no idea where to find the THESISSS.aux file (I only 
 know how to delete it).
 Any help would be much appreciated!

Best

targa

Comment: The leading comma in `@Book{,`  is the problem, as moewe says you must have the citation key before that comma so `@Book{yermack,`  then in the tex file you can use `\cite{yermack}` to reference this work. With no usable key you can not reference it and if you have that error twice you will have two entries with the empty string as key so get the error that you state.

Comment: you have tagged this biblatex but the error message suggests that you are using bibtex

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback!
moewe: unfortunately this does not help :/
David Carlisle: interestingly, the code works if I run it as pdfLateX. But it does not work with pdfLateX+MakeIndex+BibTex

Comment: You need a different key for each entry. I can assure you that if you add a key the error message will be different.

Comment: The error message talks about `LITTT.bib`, but you say your file is called `Literature.bib`. Are you sure the two files are the same?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change it here. In fact I am using the name LITTT for my literature file but in order not to confuse anyone I changed it to Literature here

Comment: If I remove the `<- line` markers the exact `.bib` file as posted here compiles fine with `biblatex`'s BibTeX style as well as `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. That means the file is OK. You can check it out on Overleaf: https://v1.overleaf.com/read/nvsfmjdxjssc

Comment: `I couldn't open database file LIT.bib` is fairly clear: BibTeX can't find the file `LIT.bib` which you gave as the source of your bib entries. Check the spelling (capitalisation might be important on your system), that the file really resides in the same directory as your `.tex` file and file permissions.

Comment: The file was indeed in the wrong folder. THANK YOU for your help! It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> As it turned out in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461802/repeated-entry-error-message-bibtex/461803#comment1161588_461802) there was a confusion about which `.bib` file was or should be read by BibTeX (there were several files with similar names in different directories).
>
> *This answer is about an earlier version of the question where the `.bib` file snippet read*
>
> ```
>   year   = {2018},
>   date   = {2018-07-30},
>   url    = {https://www.coinmarketcap.com},
> }
>
> @Book{,
>   author    = {David Yermack},
>   title     = {Handbook of Digital Currency},
> ```

Each entry in your `.bib` file must have a unique *entry key*. This entry key can be used to reference the work in the `.tex` document with `\cite{<entry key>}`. The key is given in the `.bib` entry directly after the opening curly bracket in `@<type>{` as in the scheme

```
@<type>{<entry key>,
  <field_1> = {<value_1>},
  <field_2> = {<value_2>},
  ...
  <field_n> = {<value_n>},
}
```

So you should have something like `@Book{yermack`, instead of `@Book{,`

Technically it is possible to have an empty entry key in a `.bib` file (with BibTeX, Biber won't like empty keys), but since keys must be unique you can't have two or more entries with an empty key. Additionally citing empty keys might be problematic.

Comment: I changed the Literature.bib code according to your structure, This results in the same error message. Now there are two of them :/

Comment: @targa Please update your question wit the new file. Then delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files and recompile again. Upload also the `.blg` file/the log message.

Comment: I deleted the .aux files but I do not know how to delete the .bbl files and how to find the .blg file. Do you think this is crucial for the problem solving here? Btw: I ran the code with bibtstyle plain (ecca before) but it did not work :/ (same error message as above)

Comment: @targa It *should* not be crucial, no. But it would help if we could make sure that nothing interferes. The next best thing is to run your example document in a new clean folder. As you can see at https://v1.overleaf.com/read/gkhbzzkwjqdg (new Overleaf link) the shown `.bib` file works with BibTeX's `plain` style just fine. If you are still getting the `Repeated entry` errors either your file contains more than you have shown in the question or BibTeX does not pick up the right file.

Answer (score 0):

When you got a "**Repeated entry**" error on the overleaf, you have to clean up your bibliography list. if you did paste two or more times the **same references** then this error occurs.

I could not find any guidance abt this on the internet and I spent 6 hours solving this tiny issue ((