# ERROR : BibTex subsystems ; syntax error found

Tags: biblatex, biber

I know that this is not a specific LaTeX question but a `biblatex`/Biber one, but I don't know where to ask else.

I changed my operating system from Win 7 (my Laptop) to my PC (Win 10). On my Laptop everything was fine. Biber compiled everything smooth no problems. But now I get the following error while compiling:

```
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\B8fkc98Xa4\HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib_10848.utf8,
  line 383,
syntax error: found ",",
  expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name),
    end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
```

I searched for a long timn through several posts and questions. The only similar thing I found was this question : [biber generate empty bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378495/biber-generate-empty-bbl-file)

I think the problem could be solved by doing the same (a change of the user environment variables/ TeXStudio biber path) but I don't know how to do that. Couldn't find anything similiar in TeXStudio even in the advanced settings.

Hope anyone can help me. 
The file is compiled with TeXStudio on Win 10. I know adding a MWE is an unwritten must do in this forum but I couldn't see how this would help the answear beacause the pdf is created without problem TeXStudio just can't compile the bibliography and thereby the references.

**EDIT 1 More Infos + `.bgl` file**

Might be useful to mention, that Biber produces an empty bbl file.

The `.bgl` file contains this:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'Bachelorarbeit_Human_Capital_in_the_Ind_Revolution_rework_2.blg'
[28] biber-MSWIN64:315> INFO - === 
[60] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'Bachelorarbeit_Human_Capital_in_the_Ind_Revolution_rework_2.bcf'
[156] Biber.pm:889> INFO - Found 22 citekeys in bib section 0
[170] Biber.pm:4093> INFO - Processing section 0
[184] Biber.pm:4254> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib' for section 0
[193] bibtex.pm:1523> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[254] bibtex.pm:1340> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib'
[257] Utils.pm:193> WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\B8fkc98Xa4\HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib_10848.utf8', skipping ...
[329] Utils.pm:193> WARN - year field '2009b' in entry 'Allen2009' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
[351] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\B8fkc98Xa4\HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib_10848.utf8, line 383, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
[351] Biber.pm:110> INFO - WARNINGS: 2
[351] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Comment: `biblatex`/Biber questions are perfectly on-topic here. The error is unfortunately as clear as it gets. In or around line `383` of your `.bib` file something is wrong. Quite probably you have an entry without entry key, e.g. `@article{,` instead of `@article{sigfridsson,`. Can you show us the entries from around line 383 in your `.bib` file.?

Comment: There is just one small chance of getting a slightly more helpful message: This is not the entire log that Biber will have produced, check out the entire `.blg` file (note that on Windows `.blg` files may be classified as 'performance monitor' files, but they are still plain text files you can open and view with your favourite text editor; you may have to unhide file extensions to find the file) and post it in full here. For the empty key issue see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461802/35864.

Comment: Together with `WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key` I'm quite confident that you have an entry with missing/empty entry key (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461802/35864). You just have to find it. You may be able to locate the problematic entry by searching for `{,` in your `.bib` file.

Comment: I cant find a .bbi file in my compiling directory. Where is it produced/saved?

Comment: The warning `WARN - year field '2009b' in entry 'Allen2009' is not an integer` is also something you should take at look at: You should never have to manually give the disambiguation letters for a year. `biblatex` adds them automatically if required.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.bib` not `.bbi` (fixed in the comment).

Comment: No idea how I missed an undefined entry.  Everything works fine now. Thanks pal, saved me many hours.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The high-level warning message

```
[257] Utils.pm:193> WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\Nils\AppData
\Local\Temp\B8fkc98Xa4\HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib_10848.utf8',
skipping ...
```

together with the lower-level error

```
[351] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Nils\AppData\Local
\Temp\B8fkc98Xa4\HumanCapitalIndustrialRevolution.bib_10848.utf8, line 383,
syntax error: found ",",
expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name),
  end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
```

strongly suggests that there is an entry with empty entry key in your `.bib` file. While BibTeX will accept exactly one entry with empty key, Biber will not accept any entry without key. Even in BibTeX entries without keys can't be cited.

The scheme for a `.bib` entry is

```
@<type>{<entry key>,
  <field_1> = {<value_1>},
  <field_2> = {<value_2>},
  ...
  <field_n> = {<value_n>},
}
```

where `<entry key>` should be non-empty.

You just have to find the entry that looks like

```
@article{,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
```

instead of

```
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
```

The line number in the error should be fairly accurate, just check a few lines above and below. You can also search for `{,` in your `.bib` file.

Comment: took me two hours to find that out. thanks for this response